# Upgrading Angular solution from v11.0.5 to v15.0.5

Tags: node.js, angular

**TL;DR: What is the fastest way to upgrade a legacy Angular (eg v11) to the latest version (eg v15)?**

I have an Angular 11 solution which has this `packages.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

`npm install` in the solution folder produces this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-first-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-25T20_36_55_645Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-25T20_36_55_645Z-debug-0.log
```

I then run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, which produces a lot of `WARN` statements and then shows this:

```
added 1597 packages, and audited 1598 packages in 1m

118 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

27 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 21 high, 1 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

So, I run `npm audit fix --force` which produces this:

```
added 143 packages, removed 694 packages, changed 122 packages, and audited 1047 packages in 20s

86 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

minimatch  <3.0.5
Severity: high
minimatch ReDoS vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-f8q6-p94x-37v3
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/minimatch

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

So, I run `npm audit fix --force` again, and it shows this:

```
removed 1 package, changed 1 package, and audited 1046 packages in 3s

86 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Now, if I run `ng serve` I get this:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (15.0.5) is greater than your local version (11.1.2). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^15.0.0,
but Angular version 11.2.14 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/
```

I visit `https://update.angular.io/` and select from v11 to v12, as it also states

> You can't run ng update to update Angular applications more than one
> major version at a time.

So, from `https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-12.0` I run `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`, which produces:

```
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 12.2.18 to perform the update.
√ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 31 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires "^15.0.0" (extended), would install "12.2.17").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=4.8.2 <5.0", would install "4.3.5").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-7soZ7i\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

So I run `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 --force` which produces a lot of output, but appears to work.

Next, I moved to `https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-13.0` which states I should run `ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13` and produces:

```
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 13.3.10 to perform the update.
√ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 31 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires "^15.0.0" (extended), would install "13.3.12").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=4.8.2 <5.0", would install "4.6.4").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-p47IAP\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

So I run it like this: `ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force` which also produces a lot of output but finally appears to complete successfully.

This moves me to `https://update.angular.io/?v=13.0-14.0` which states I should run `ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14`. I see this:

```
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 14.2.10 to perform the update.
√ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 31 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires "^15.0.0" (extended), would install "14.2.12").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-wQ5M5Z\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

So I run `ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14 --force` which, again, appears to complete successfully.

This leads me to `https://update.angular.io/?v=14.0-15.0` and running the command `ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15` which appears to complete, as well - fortunately, this time, without the need for `--force`.

Running `ng serve` works.

Is this the best way to upgrade a legacy Angular project to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `ng update` command is the recommended path to update angular applications.

With the latest CLI Versions, you can update only one version at a time (in the past, you could bump two or more versions at once). The idea behind this is to be able to run all the needed migrations when updating to a newer version without the risk of conflicts. The CLI runs the migrations for you.

The errors you got, like:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-first-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.4" from the root project
```

Are not related to Angular, but to npm (I guess you are using npm 7+). Newer npm versions will check that peer dependencies versions are respected and throw an error in case of a wrong version (as you are getting). From npm 7 release docs:

> npm 7 will block installations if an upstream dependency conflict is
> present that cannot be automatically resolved.
>
> You have the option to retry with --force to bypass the conflict or
> --legacy-peer-deps command to ignore peer dependencies entirely (this behavior is similar to versions 4-6).

In general, I would advise avoiding using `--force` while updating your dependencies and trying to find the right combination of versions between the libraries.